# How to get the number of swapped out LWPs in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I use `vmstat | head -3` in Solaris to check the process situation and get this

```
kthr memory page disk faults cpu
r b w swap free re mf pi po fr de sr s4 s5 -- -- in sy cs us sy id
0 0 0 100548720 6357568 219 3300 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 2193 6771 2256 0 1 98
```

the `w` means `the number of swapped out lightweight processes (LWPs) that are waiting for processing resources to finish.` We use this data to monitor system conditions.

But running the command in Redhat get this result

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu -----
r b swpd free buff cache si so bi bo in cs us sy id wa st
0 0 784968 348724 28 44781148 0 1 16 49 7 9 1 0 98 1 0
```

The **w** in column 3 is missing, I try to find a replacement in another command

use the `top` command

```
top - 20:28:12 up 5 days, 22:24, 7 users, load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.06
Tasks: 725 total, 1 running, 724 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 0.3 us, 0.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.0 id, 0.3 wa, 0.1 hi, 0.1 si, 0.0 st
MiB Mem : 48087.3 total, 301.6 free, 4029.0 used, 43756.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 16384.0 total, 15617.9 free, 766.1 used. 3496.9 avail Mem
```

`1 running` is not the data I need

Use the `ps -efL | head -3` command

```
UID PID PPID LWP C NLWP STIME TTY TIME CMD
root   1   0  1  0    1  Jun 22 ? 00:00:22 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 18
root   2   0  2  0    1 Jun 22 ? 00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

The `NLWP` here is also not the data I need

Is there any way to get the same data as the w column of vmstat in solaris?